# jQuery: get text from within a single element which is using <br/> instead of child elements

Tags: jquery, string, parsing

Using jQuery, I need to get the "Item SKU" from an element that looks something like this:

```
<b class="cart-item-name">
    "Item Name "<br> 
    "Item Description" <br>
    "Item SKU"<br>
</b>
```

There is no consistent pattern to the actual text the element contains, no regular length, repeated letter patterns, or anything like that.  The only thing that is always true is that there are three lines, in the same order, divided by line breaks, and the third will be the SKU I need.

How can I get the info that I need?

EDIT:
To clarify, the different text in my snippet above will be replaced by a text string specific to an item, so for example it could be:

```
<b class="cart-item-name">
    "Cool Product 123"<br> 
    "It's cool!" <br>
    "I123-abc"<br>
</b>
```

or maybe:

```
<b class="cart-item-name">
    "Dumb product"<br> 
    "It's stupid!" <br>
    "abc-456"<br>
</b>
```

I just need to get the third line of text, whatever it is.

Comment: this means what? `I need to get the "Item SKU" from an element`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** and **[`html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/)** , and try something as following

```js
alert($('b.art-item-name').html().split('<br>')[2]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b class="cart-item-name">
    "Item Name "<br> 
    "Item Description" <br>
    "Item SKU"<br>
</b>
```

Comment: Works great (after correcting a small typo).  I hadn't thought of pulling it as html.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you just want to check if "Item SKU" exists?

```
  if($('.cart-tem-name').text().IndexOf("Item SKU") >= 0){
       //do stuff
  }
```